# Regex - repeating 2 letters on by one

Tags: java, regex

I have a code that generates some word using some logic and i have regex 1 (see down). But i need to generate right word such as words 1. My logic includes mathcing pattern i mentioned. I need right pattern to generate words such as in words 1 instead 2. The logic for the pattern is:

1. the word starts with the uppercase vowel or consonant
2. the length is 2 or more symbols (of the whole word)
3. there is should not be more than two vowels or consonants in a row

```
Aakemenkyu
Klepathass
Waknampite
Flaetobsak
Oladkinqyt
Mmalinnetj
```

etc

these are words 1

`[A-Z](([aeiouy]|[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]){1,2})*`

this is regex 1

This regex doesn't work and i have next words generated by my code logic:

```
Ijythlzuoe
Tervkpxyib
Ifuemkoeui
Mqjtobojex
Ephyrjiuau
```

these are words 2

for example, in the word `Ijythlzuoe` there is `thl` (consonants repeating 3 times in a row) and `uoe` (vowels repeating)

Help, please.

Comment: What language of regex?

Comment: I don't really understand your last paragraph, but your regex seems to match all of your examples. Which examples do you want it to match, and which ones do you not want it to match?

Comment: @xdhmoore I think the op is trying to generate string using a given regex(reverse engineering).

Comment: @ansvir, can you clarify? The post starts with "I need regex...", so I am just guessing that the word "generates" really is intended to say "matches"...

Comment: What should be the result for `Aabbaacc`?

Comment: @xdhmoore, the language is java

Comment: @xdhmoore, sorry for bad explanation, i meant that i have code that generates some word using some logic and i have regex i specified. But i need to generate right word such as in the first paragraph. My logic includes mathcing (you are right) pattern that i specified. I need right pattern to generate words such as in the first paragraph instead last. The logic for the pattern is that the word starts with the uppercase vowel or consonant, the length is 2 or more symbols (of the whole word) and there is should not be more than two vowels or consonants in a row

Comment: @Toto, the result should be true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex, `(?=[A-Z][A-Za-z])(?i)(?!.*[aeiouy]{3}|.*[^aeiouy]{3})[a-z]+` should meet your requirement.

Explanation of the regex from [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lu7UOb/1):

[image]

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of("Aakemenkyu",
                  "Klepathass",
                  "Waknampite",
                  "Flaetobsak",
                  "Oladkinqyt",
                  "Mmalinnetj",
                  "Ijythlzuoe",
                  "Tervkpxyib",
                  "Ifuemkoeui",
                  "Mqjtobojex",
                  "Ephyrjiuau").forEach( s -> {
                      System.out.println(s + " => " + s.matches("(?=[A-Z][A-Za-z])(?i)(?!.*[aeiouy]{3}|.*[^aeiouy]{3})[a-z]+"));
                  });
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Aakemenkyu => true
Klepathass => true
Waknampite => true
Flaetobsak => true
Oladkinqyt => true
Mmalinnetj => true
Ijythlzuoe => false
Tervkpxyib => false
Ifuemkoeui => false
Mqjtobojex => false
Ephyrjiuau => false
```

Comment: It matches `Aaabbii`: https://regex101.com/r/C3eVF0/1

Answer (score 6):

I think by "generates" you actually want to say "matches".

You can use this regex to validate 1-2 consonants followed by 1-2 vowels, and vice versa:

```
/^(([aeiouy]){1,2})?(([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]){1,2}([aeiouy]){1,2})*(([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]){1,2})?$/i
```

Test case using JavaScript, but this regex should work in any language:

```js
const regex = /^(([aeiouy]){1,2})?(([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]){1,2}([aeiouy]){1,2})*(([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]){1,2})?$/i;
[
  'Aakemenkyu',
  'Klepathass',
  'Waknampite',
  'Flaetobsak',
  'Oladkinqyt',
  'Mmalinnetj',
  'Ijythlzuoe',
  'Tervkpxyib',
  'Ifuemkoeui',
  'Mqjtobojex',
  'Ephyrjiuau'
].forEach(str => {
  console.log(str + ' => ' + regex.test(str));
});
```

Output:

```
Aakemenkyu => true
Klepathass => true
Waknampite => true
Flaetobsak => true
Oladkinqyt => true
Mmalinnetj => true
Ijythlzuoe => false
Tervkpxyib => false
Ifuemkoeui => false
Mqjtobojex => false
Ephyrjiuau => false
```

Explanation:

- `^` - anchor at start of string
- `(` - start of group #1 (could be made a non-capturing group `(?:`...`)`)

  - `([aeiouy]){1,2}` - one to two vowels
- `)?` - end of group #1, `?` makes this optional
- `(` - start of group #2

  - `([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]){1,2}` - one to two consonants
  - `([aeiouy]){1,2}` - one to two vowels
- `)*` - end of group #2, zero to multiple repetitions
- `(` - start of group #3

  - `([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]){1,2}` - one to two consonants
- `)?` - end of group #3, `?` makes this optional
- `$` - anchor at end of string
- use the `i` flag to ignore case

Comment: @Toto: "consonants and vowels should not repeat more than 2 times", that's what this regex does, and what JvdV's answer does too. The confusing part is that the OP includes `y` in the vowels list.

Comment: @Toto: Sorry, I don't get it. As I read the OP's question, `aabbaacc` should match.

Comment: Nice answer. What @Toto might have meant is that all input starts with a uppercase which is why "aabbaacc" shouldn't match?

Comment: After clarification from OP, it appears you are right (and get my vote!).

Comment: (I think  it would also match an empty string)

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Yes that is correct. However, the OP uses that part of pattern generation, thus will not have an empty string. My regex however ignores case, and after clarification by the OP, it turns out that it should be initial caps, followed by lowercase letters. I did not add the positive lookahead and ignore case switch in the regex because the regex engine was unknown.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
^(?=[A-Z][a-z]*$)(?i)(?!.*[aeiouy]{3}|.*[^aeiouy\n]{3})[a-z]+$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rad5BA/1)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?=[A-Z][a-z]*$)` - Positive lookahead to start a string with a uppercase alpha while remainder is lowercase upto end.
- `(?i)` - Inline modifier to match remainder case-insensitive.
- `(?!` - Open negative lookahead:

  - `.*[aeiouy]{3}` - Match upto any three consecutive characters from class.
  - `|` - Or:
  - `.*[^aeiouy\n]{3}` - Match upto any three consecutive characters not in class.
  - `)` - Close negative lookahead.
- `[a-z]+` - 1+ characters from a-z (case-insensitive).
- `$` - End string anchor.

Comment: I think it should be `^(?=[A-Z][a-z]+$)` to match at least 2 characters)